# access 2013 crashes when opening report in design view

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013

I am in the process of migrating several critical Access applications from Access 2007 to Access 2013. Generally this is going smoothly, but I am now facing a major issue.
Foreword:
1. By migrating I mean using the same db's (they are in accdb format), just tweaking them to compensate for the difference in the UI. (The end-users need not see any ribbons at all, except when previewing reports)
2. The applications are front-ends to a SQL Server back-end. No critical information is stored on the applications themselves, all Access tables are temporary in nature.
3. However, many Queries are run in the applications. I am slowly migrating all I can to SQL Server Views and stored procedures, but there is a lot and it's slow going.
4. This is not an anti-virus problem. I do not have Symantec installed.
The Issue:
**One of the reports has 4 (four) sub-reports in it. Whenever I try to open it in Design View Access 2013 crashes.**
The report opens in design view just fine when I open the application with Access 2007. Also, it opens just fine in Access 2013 when I remove all the sub-reports.
I have tried to copy the report to a new one.
I have tried to redesign it from scratch in Access 2013.
And every time the same thing happens: when I exit design-view (after having successfully added the sub-reports without any indication of a problem!) and try to reopen the report in design view, Access 2013 crashes.
I have searched the Internet for any kind of solution, but nothing seems to come close to this problem.

Please, can anyone help me?

Comment: could any VBA be causal? do you have any VBA associated with the report? i.e. stuck in a loop

Comment: Thank you, you just missed me answering my own question. No, I constantly de-compile and re-compile and compact the apps.

Answer (score 0):

OOPS...
I thought I had checked all four of the sub-reports.
Turns out the underlying problem came from one of them...
It was (I think) a compatibility issue. Most of the forms and reports in these applications are a legacy handed down from Access XP (which might have been converted from even earlier versions).
Anyway, I re-designed the sub-report from scratch and everything is OK.

General Piece of Advice:
When "converting" to newer versions of MS-Access, always make sure you can open **all** the objects in the application.